# rendering Image from the Django server in Angular 8

Tags: python, django, angular, api

Following are my models, views and serializers file. API endpoints are working fine and in Angular I am able to print name and place from the Restaurant model. However, I couldn't find the way to render and show the image ( which I have stored in photo object). My API shows the image when I type:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/iconfinder_thefreeforty_trolle.png

However, if I use

```
<div class='container' >
  <div  *ngFor= "let restaurant of restaurants | async; let i=index">
        <h2> {{restaurant.name}} in {{restaurant.place}}  </h2>
        <small>{{restaurant.photo}}</small>
        <img src={{restaurant.photo}} >
        </div>
  </div>
```

I see no image, the "{{restaurant.photo}}" points to the url 'media/images/iconfinder_thefreeforty_trolle.png', but not able to show the image.
Is this the right way to render an image from django server to angular?

My django files are following:
**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=False)
    place=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def restaurant_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all()
        serializer = RestaurantSerializer(restaurants, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RestaurantSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def restaurant_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Restaurant.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = RestaurantSerializer(restaurant)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        restaurant = RestaurantSerializer(restaurant, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Restaurant

class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Restaurant
        fields=('id','name','place','photo')
```

Comment: If  `restaurant.photo` is a relative url, like `media/images/iconfinder_thefreeforty_trolle.png`, then is not going to work. It should be an absolute url, like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/iconfinder_thefreeforty_trolle.png`

Comment: I think src={{restaurant.photo}} points to http://localhost:4200/media/images/iconfinder_thefreeforty_trolle.png instead of >http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/iconfinder_thefreeforty_trolle.png and there is no file such as this. So it throws file not found. But how to make it absolute url?

Comment: If is a relative url, like the one you post, you just need to concat the base url of your API to the `restaurant.photo` value. For example `<img src="{{api.url + restaurant.photo}}" >`, to test it quickly hard code it, `<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{restaurant.photo}}" >`

Comment: it is working with ``` <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{restaurant.photo} ``` but not with this api.url way, just to be sure, where would you define api.url?

Comment: i have endpoint defined in the service file, like `endpoint: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurants/';' and I tried to use that endpoint in html but didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it was just an example for not hard coding. You could define a string property in the component  `apiUrl` with the value `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, and just take it from there. A good practice is to store all this parameters in the environments files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a relative value, like the one you are using, then you are referencing a resource within your website.

Because your API is an external resource, the value of the `src` property of the `img` tag must be an absolute URL.

In your case the value should be, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/iconfinder_thefreeforty_trolle.png`.

Quick and dirty, `<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{restaurant.photo}}" >` (just to use as an example, it is not a good practice, use environments for this kind of parameters).

[Answer from the comments]