# image will not display Django3 serving Angular8

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

similar to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866348/rendering-image-from-the-django-server-in-angular-8) but that solution would not work for me. I cannot get my image to render with the Angular frontend.

In the browser `{{recipe.photo}}` displays `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/photo1_mMxzxU0.png`. From the other SO question I thought since this was an absolute url pointing to the image it would work..

**html**

```
<div *ngIf= "recipes">
    <ul *ngFor ="let recipe of recipes">
        {{recipe.name}}
        {{recipe.photo}}
        <img src={{recipe.photo}} height="150" >
</div>
```

**models.py**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=False, blank=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class RestaurantRecipes(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializerShort
```

**serializers.py**

```
class RecipeSerializerShort(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['name','photo']
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users///backend/images/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My images are in this folder `/Users///backend/images/images/IMAGES_HERE`

Comment: So `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/photo1_mMxzxU0.png` displays the image in the browser? But not when bound to to src element?

Comment: if i put `<img src = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/photo1_mMxzxU0.png">` in the browser it does not render the image

Comment: But you copy that url as is in the browser, does that work? Because if it does, then you should have some error in the console when using angular

Comment: it does not work if i copy that url and put in the address bar either

Comment: That's the first thing you should check... What about `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photo1_mMxzxU0.png`

Comment: good point, i tried that also same result

Comment: Ok, so it's not an angular problem at all, it's just to do with django configuration. Hopefully somebody else can help you

Comment: ok, i updated my question to show a few more django details thanks

Answer (score 0):

The brackets, [], tell Angular to evaluate the template expression

**try this :**

```
<img [src]="recipe.photo" height="150" >
```

**instead of this :**

```
<img src={{recipe.photo}} height="150" >
```